# Why there are lots of 0.js 1.js 404 file

Tags: next.js

I build my nextjs app and then run `yarn start`,
I find there are a lot of 404 files.
I want to know what are these files and how can I remove these files,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887316/next-js-404-error-for-all-preloaded-links

Comment: thanks!!!I have not  heard of `prefetch` before my ask the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem

1.`<Link href='posts/0' prefetch={false}/>`

2.Change `<Link href='posts/0'/>`to `<Link href='posts/[page]' as='posts/0'/>`

reference:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link
- [Next.js 404 error for all preloaded links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887316/next-js-404-error-for-all-preloaded-links)

thanks George!