# Next js error in console _next/data/QPTTgJmZl2jVsyHQ_IfQH/blog/post/21/.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ssg

I receive an error in the console in my Next.js site.

```
GET https://example.com/_next/data/QPTTgJmZl2jVsyHQ_IfQH/blog/post/21/.json net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I don't understand why it's happened. Maybe I'm using the router incorrectly?

my link code:

```
    <Link href="/blog/post/[id]" as={`/blog/post/${id}`}>
```

for fetch data for post i use  `getStaticPaths` & `getStaticProps`.

My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887316/next-js-404-error-for-all-preloaded-links), but I have it only in production. I try to use `prefetch` but it did not work.

Comment: Could you find a solution? @Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to be something related to the props your page need.

If you inspect the requests of a production build SSR or SSG page the initial pageProps returns from this endpoint: `_next/data/....`

So check your server console or add some debug helpers to understand deeply what is happening in your `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`.

[fyi](https://www.loudnoises.us/solving-next-static-pages-js-404-not-found/)